# Settimeout javascript function not working

Tags: javascript

I have a `js` code wherein i have a `for` loop and inside it, I have a `settimeout` function to set the color of each of the keys of a piano depending on the list array of piano notes(score). The piano key stays in orange color for a particular duration and then goes back to the original color. But it happens so that, the `settimeout` doesn't always work as suggested.

```
setTimeout(function() { document.getElementById(val_key).style.fill = current_color; },duration);
```

Any help on the same is very well appreciated.

Comment: please edit and place the code including for loop

Comment: The loop is pretty big as its from abcweb-min.js and not something I have written. I want they keys to go on and off - but sometimes, because of some reason, settimeout works initially, but later on doesnt work exactly as expected.

Comment: “doesnt always work as suggested” – what is that even supposed to mean?

Comment: @poke - i meant settimeout executes well initially but not later on in the loop.

Comment: Use `js beautifier` http://jsbeautifier.org/ and show us the for-loop. Otherwise it is near impossible to help. The `setTimeout` api is pretty reliable and shouldn't cause any grieve.

Comment: All loop iterations are considered *instantaneous*. There is no time difference between them. So all the timeouts fire at the same time `duration`. So they will quickly overwrite themselves, making only the very last one take effect.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass distinct `duration`. Since the complete code is not present, I can only assume it is executing all at once since the duration is same.

Also you need to use [**IIFE & closure**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

```
for (var i = 0; i <=someLength; i++) {
    (function(index) {
        setTimeout(function() { 
          document.getElementById(val_key).style.fill = current_color;
      }, i * someDuration);
    })(i); // pass value of i
}
```